# tableview update cells at wrong indexpath

Tags: tableview, xcode8, indexpath

i´ve got a problem with tableview.

i have a list of audio track and i check every track if this track actually exists. if not, i set a deleted image over the artwork in cells image view.

```
    //SET DELETED IMAGE IF TRACK NOT EXISTS
    if (!trackExists && cell.trackImageView.subviews.count < 1) {

       UIImageView *deletedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
       deletedImageView.image = [self resizeImageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellDeletedImage"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60)];
       [cell.trackImageView addSubview:deletedImageView];

    }
```

sometimes when i reload the tableview, the deleted image is on existing tracks. i know there are more efficient ways to do this, but i tried and tried and i ended up here.

also i logged this method, and it puts the deleted image even when there is no log.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, that if you're using table views as they are designed, that you are reusing cells. Does this happen when you scroll the table up and down a few times too? Does one cell that has the deleted image suddenly not have it if you scroll again?

It sounds like the reused cell still has a reference to that deleted image.

It's not quite clear where you *add* that image view, but I suggest that you move that code to the custom class for your table view cell (or create one if it doesn't exist). Subsequently in `prepareForReuse`, ensure that the image view is removed or hidden.

```
@class TrackTableViewCell : UITableViewCell 
{
    - (void) prepareForReuse 
    {
         //Remove / hide image view
    }

    - (void) setAsDeleted 
    {
        //Add / show image view
    }
}
```

(Forgive objective-c syntax errors! I've been using Swift for a while now.)